# Applying class over a specific set of table rows in jsp

Tags: css, jsp

I wish to apply specific class on a group of table rows and not on all the table rows of a table, but not getting any solution for this. Therefore please help me.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What do you want to do? What style? What table?

Answer (score 0):

Based on conditions in JSP you may apply css style to the table rows, Some thing like
 
  `<tr class="${condition?'className':''}"></tr>`